# How to drop values less than 5% of all data pandas?

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I have following values. Some of them presents only ones. How to drop values that less than 5% of total values? For example, value PIP1 presents only one and it's obviously less than 5% of all values. How to drop all similar values? And possibly for all columns

[image: valu]

Answer (score 2):

Use `value_counts` with `normalize` to get the percentage, filter the counts by value, then use `isin`:

```
counts = df['col'].value_counts(normalize=True)
df[df['col'].isin(counts.gt(0.05).index)]
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! counts.get(0.05) returns specific value with 0.05, but i need values equal or greater 0.05

Comment: It’s `gt` for greater than, not get

Comment: Yea, you right! But still after this value_counts shows values with 1 counts

Comment: Yes, df = df[df[col].isin(counts.gt(0.05).index)]

Comment: The shape of data set before and after is the same

Comment: Try `df.loc[counts.gt(0.05)]`

Answer (score 0):

```
counts = df_[col].value_counts(normalize=True)
return df_[df[col].isin(counts[counts.gt(0.05)].index)]
```